ERROR SparkContext: Failed to add file java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar to Spark not Found
Please help me fix the above errors based on the code I used

The proccesing_data.py code is used to process data using spark-streaming

import logging
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, explode, to_date, first, last, max, min, avg, sum, lit
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, ArrayType, StringType, DoubleType, LongType, IntegerType
import time


# Cấu hình logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Các thông số kết nối
kafka_topic_name = "finnhub_data"
kafka_bootstrap_servers = "localhost:9092"


mysql_host_name = "localhost"
mysql_port_no = "3306"
mysql_database_name = "finnhub_processed"
mysql_driver_class = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"  # Cập nhật driver class
mysql_table_name = "processed_trade_data"
mysql_user_name = "tuanle"
mysql_password = "123456"
mysql_jdbc_url = f"jdbc:mysql://{mysql_host_name}:{mysql_port_no}/{mysql_database_name}"

cassandra_host_name = "localhost"
cassandra_port_no = "9042"
cassandra_keyspace_name = "finnhub_data"
cassandra_table_name = "raw_trade_data"


def save_to_cassandra(df, epoch_id):
   logger.info(f"Saving batch {epoch_id} to Cassandra")
  
   df_to_save = df.select(
       col("symbol"),
       (col("trade_time") / 1000).cast("timestamp").alias("trade_time"),
       col("price"),
       col("volume"),
       col("conditions"),
       col("company")
   )
  
   df_to_save.write \
       .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
       .mode("append") \
       .options(table=cassandra_table_name, keyspace=cassandra_keyspace_name) \
       .save()
  
   logger.info(f"Batch {epoch_id} saved to Cassandra successfully")


def process_and_save_to_mysql(spark):
   logger.info("Starting to process data from Cassandra and save to MySQL")


   df_cassandra = spark.read \
       .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
       .options(table=cassandra_table_name, keyspace=cassandra_keyspace_name) \
       .load()


   df_processed = df_cassandra \
       .withColumn("trade_date", to_date(col("trade_time"))) \
       .groupBy("symbol", "trade_date") \
       .agg(
           first("price").alias("open_price"),
           last("price").alias("close_price"),
           max("price").alias("high_price"),
           min("price").alias("low_price"),
           avg("price").alias("avg_price"),
           sum("volume").alias("total_volume")
       ) \
       .withColumn("processed_time", lit(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))


   df_processed.write \
       .jdbc(url=mysql_jdbc_url,
             table=mysql_table_name,
             mode="append",
             properties={
                 "user": mysql_user_name,
                 "password": mysql_password,
                 "driver": mysql_driver_class
             })


   logger.info("Data processed and saved to MySQL successfully")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   logger.info("Data Processing Application Started ...")


   # Khởi tạo Spark Session và định nghĩa cấu hình cần thiết
   spark = SparkSession.builder \
       .appName("PySpark Structured Streaming with Kafka, Cassandra, and MySQL") \
       .config("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", True) \
       .config("spark.jars", f"file:///home/tuanle/areaapache/software/spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/jsr305-3.0.0.jar,file:///home/tuanle/areaapache/software/spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.5.1.jar,file:///home/tuanle/areaapache/software/spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.5.2.jar,file:///usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar,file:///home/tuanle/areaapache/software/spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/kafka-clients-3.8.0.jar") \
       .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 4) \
       .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandra_host_name) \
       .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", cassandra_port_no) \
       .config("spark.sql.mysql.host", mysql_host_name) \
       .config("spark.sql.mysql.port", mysql_port_no) \
       .config("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", "60000") \
       .master("local[4]") \
       .getOrCreate()


   spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")


   logger.info("Spark Session initialized successfully")


   finnhub_df = spark \
       .readStream \
       .format("kafka") \
       .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
       .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
       .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
       .load()


   logger.info("Printing Schema of finnhub_df:")
   finnhub_df.printSchema()


   finnhub_schema = StructType([
       StructField("data", ArrayType(StructType([
           StructField("c", ArrayType(StringType())),
           StructField("p", DoubleType()),
           StructField("s", StringType()),
           StructField("t", LongType()),
           StructField("v", IntegerType()),
           StructField("company", StringType())
       ]))),
       StructField("type", StringType())
   ])


   finnhub_df1 = finnhub_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp")
   finnhub_df2 = finnhub_df1.select(from_json(col("value"), finnhub_schema).alias("finnhub"), "timestamp")
   finnhub_df3 = finnhub_df2.select("finnhub.data", "timestamp")
   finnhub_df4 = finnhub_df3.select(explode("data").alias("trade_data"), "timestamp")
   finnhub_df5 = finnhub_df4.select(
       col("trade_data.s").alias("symbol"),
       col("trade_data.t").alias("trade_time"),
       col("trade_data.p").alias("price"),
       col("trade_data.v").alias("volume"),
       col("trade_data.c").alias("conditions"),
       col("trade_data.company").alias("company"),
       col("timestamp")
   )


   query_cassandra = finnhub_df5 \
       .writeStream \
       .trigger(processingTime='15 seconds') \
       .outputMode("append") \
       .foreachBatch(save_to_cassandra) \
       .start()


   try:
       while True:
           time.sleep(300)  # Wait for 5 minutes
           process_and_save_to_mysql(spark)
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       logger.info("Application interrupted. Stopping streams...")
       query_cassandra.stop()
       spark.stop()
       logger.info("Application stopped successfully")
   except Exception as e:
       logger.error(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
       query_cassandra.stop()
       spark.stop()
       logger.info("Application stopped due to an error")

Error encountered after running spark_streaming:
Here's a concise summary of the errors encountered in the log:

Missing JAR files: Several JAR files were not found in the specified Spark directory, including:

jsr305-3.0.0.jar

spark-cassandra-connector_2.13-3.5.1.jar

spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13-3.5.2.jar

spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.13-3.5.2.jar

kafka-clients-3.8.0.jar



Kafka-related error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater This error suggests that the Kafka-related dependencies are missing or not properly loaded.

Scala-related error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less This error indicates a problem with Scala dependencies, possibly due to version incompatibility.

Cassandra-related error: An error occurred while trying to load data from Cassandra: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less


2024-10-01 10:11:54,931 - INFO - Application stopped due to an error
2024-10-01 10:11:54,931 - INFO - Closing down clientserver connection
I try dowload all jar: jsr305-3.0.0.jar, spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.5.1.jar, spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.5.2.jar, kafka-clients-3.8.0.jar
Then move the JAR files into Spark's jars folder and Update CLASSPATH:
I run the command: spark-shell --version and here is the result: SPARK version 3.5.2 Using Scala version 2.12.18, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_422
The settings I downloaded: Cassandra 4.1.6, MySQL, Hadoop-3.4.0, mysql-connector-j-9.0.0, kafka_2.12-3.8.0, sbt-1.10.2, spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3, scala-2.13.14
But when running Spark I still get the error. How to fix it. Please help me in detail. Thank you everyone
If possible, what can I reinstall? Please give me advice to avoid deleting everything and downloading again. Please help me

First as a friendly, constructive feedback: your post is too broad and is really asking multiple questions so it's likely to be voted for closure.
Second, I'll answer specifically the issue relating to the Spark Cassandra connector. Providing the connector JAR in your application typically doesn't work because you are likely to miss providing all the dependencies.
Instead we recommend that you provide the Maven coordinates of the Cassandra connector to --packages or spark.jars.packages so that the connector and all its dependencies are placed on the path of the Spark driver and executors. For example, launch a Spark shell with:
$ spark-shell
    --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1 \
    --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.5.1
    --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions

Similarly for your application:
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        ...
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.5.1")
        ...

As a side note if I may give you some friendly advice, you are more likely to get help if (1) you break up your question into separate multiple posts, with each post focusing on just one problem, and (2) provide a minimal sample code for that one component (not a large chunk of code you expect someone else to troubleshoot for you).
For guidance, see How to ask a good question. Cheers!
